# android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView in a Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I have an app, where I have a slidingtabs with classes based on the `Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment`. In one of these Fragments I have an `android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView` in the axml file. Everytime when I want to debug the project on my smartphone, it crashes and says: `An unhandled exception occured.`. I tried removing the `RecyclerView` from the axml file, it works. So what can I do the use the `reyclerview` in that fragment?

Comment: You should post the actual error message you are getting.

Comment: `An unhandled exception occured.` There are no further information...

Comment: So no stack trace? No nothing? Does it show which line of code actually fails?

Comment: No nothing, thats a bit weird